# Regex not working as expected for Alphanumeric and Some special characters

Tags: c#, regex, string, string-matching

Can anyone let me know the regex for accepting Alphanumeric, a blank space and some special characters? Nothing is mandatory here.

i have already tried:

```
@"[-\w.?!,\(\)\-\+\'\;\:\&\""\@\s]"
```

but this is not working. I am doing this validation on server side and not in javascript.
The special characters it should accept are: 
.?!,()-_+';:&""@ 
123abc&@ - valid,
123 - valid,
abc - valid,
&"@ - valid,
213^ - invalid,
^% - Invalid.

Comment: Can you provide a couple examples of strings that would pass the regex?

Comment: What's your test case? and how is it failing?

Comment: The special characters it should accept are:
.?!,()\-_+';:&""@
123abc&@ - valid,
123 - valid,
abc - valid,
&"@ - valid,
213^ - invalid,
^% - Invalid.

Comment: `@"^[-\w.?!,()+';:&""@\s]+$"`

Comment: @SamIam this is my test string : "123abc()^%"
This should fail, but its passing rite now.

Comment: @Mayur please edit your post instead of adding comments. Also I'd recommend searching for similar questions (like https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+regex+match+alphanumeric+whole+string) as it feels your current question is quite a duplicate of at least one older question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AvinashRaj said, you have to use anchors. Currently you do not use anchors, so the regex you provided finds matching sequence in the middle of given string and returns a match.

Also you can simplify your regex by removing unnecessary escaping symbols.

Regex:

```
^[-\w.?!,()+';:&"@\s]+$
```

C# string:

```
@"^[-\w.?!,()+';:&""@\s]+$"
```

Comment: thank you its working fine now. I missed out on the anchor tag. :)